# Is is possible each cell of a numpy array iteratively from a function?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Was not sure how exactly to word the question but here is the problem:

I essentially have an empty array S that is of shape n * n. I also have an array of data R, of shape n * m. My goal is for S[i][j] = some func combining R[i] R[j].

This is the code I wrote to accomplish what I want:

```
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
        S[i][j] = foo(R[i], R[j])
```

I'd like to know if there is an existing numpy function that can do something like this, so I do not have to write the for loops.

Answer (score 0):

In numpy we generally write `foo` to to be "array aware" to avoid needing to loop over our inputs. For example, you could take this function `crossAddF` and write an array aware version `crossAddArray`:

```
def crossAdd(a, b):
    S = np.zeros([len(a), len(b)])
    for i in range(len(a)):
        for j in range(len(b)):
            S[i][j] = a[i] + b[j]
    return S

def corssAddArray(a, b):
    a = np.reshape(a, [len(a), 1])
    b = np.reshape(b, [1, len(b)])
    return a + b
```

That being said, I realize that we sometimes need to work with functions that weren't meant for numpy that we can't easily re-write or change. In that case `numpy.vectorize` can be useful. Keep in mind that `vectorize` can be slower than other implementations of the same functionality. Here's an example:

```
def foo(i, j):
    return float(i) + float(j)

def crossAddUsingVectorize(a, b):
    a = np.reshape(a, [len(a), 1])
    b = np.reshape(b, [1, len(b)])
    return np.vectorize(foo)(a, b)
```

My examples also use numpy's [broadcasting feature](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) it might be worth reading about if you're not already familiar with it.